# Can we dynamically load tables into spotfire based on some input selection

Tags: spotfire

I have a text area with dropdown selection with values A,B,C

The need is if I select A from dropdown data from table A gets loaded into spotfire if I select B from dropdown data from table B gets loaded respectively for every selection.

Comment: I would not attempt to control the data flow in this manner. Instead, I'd have all of the tables linked up, and use data on demand to limit what is being pulled. Spotfire ins't a data management tool

Comment: I agree with @scsimon here. you absolutely *can* use IronPython to load different data tables/information links, but it's probably a Bad Idea and will result in brittle code. could you tell a little more about what your end goal is? why do you think you need this approach? make sure you aren't falling into an "XY Problem": http://xyproblem.info/